# Error when importing file from Codelabs tutorial

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a CodeLab tutorial for adding Chromecast support. I've downloaded the files and when I try to import them into Android Studio I get this error:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and latest tool build and Gradle. What can I try to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out. It ended up being because the Codelab application used in the tutorial was so old and outdated I needed to change a few things in the Gradle and manifest.

In the Gradle file I changed the build tools to a later version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

I updated the compiled version to 28 plus updated the support libraries. I also had to remove the unique app id and remove the target sdk from in manifest. Finally I updated the wrapper settings, and it started to work correctly.